What is the Proper Way to Configure Blazor Web App Navigation to Handle 404?
I have converted my Blazor Server-side Application to the new Blazor Web App project.  Everything works as expected except for when I navigate to a view that does not exist.
I can reproduce what I am experiencing by creating a default Blazor Web App project in Visual Studio, launching via F5, and navigating to /somepaththatdoesnotexist (or any URL that does not exist).
What I experience is a blank white page.
What is the recommended configuration to restore the "not found" experience of the previous Blazor Server-side projects?

In my website, I use app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode/{0}"); and I have a custom error page that display a content accordingly to the statuscode

@Bisjob I did see that, but that's not the same.  The URL gets redirected to a new location rather than the in-place address that the user visited.  To see the behavior that I am after, please create a "Blazor Server-side" project in Visual Studio, run it, and visit a URL that doesn't exist.  You should get a clean Sorry, there's nothing at this address. message with the URL intact.  No configuration is necessary, either.

Hi, there's a discussion about this case. I also noticed the same issue as yours, and we could see that in blazor server .net 7, we have <NotFound> in App.razor while in .net 8 blazor web app Routes.razor, we don't have <NotFound> in it, and even if we added it manually, it won't work. According to the ideas shared in that discussion, we might let app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects handle it(404 error)

Indeed in .NET8 there is no more the  tag in the router. And even if you add it, no matter the rendering mode it doesn't work (at least I couldn't make it work). And today when you create a new template, you've got a blank page for a 404. The only suitable solution I found is to use the app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects and create your own 404 page

Dang @Bisjob thank you for relaying the bad news. This is an obvious regression from the prior experience.   If you want to promote your comment as an answer I will accept it.

This is done, thank you @Mike-E

When creating a new project from the Blazor app template in .NET8, the <NotFound> tag is not present anymore in the router. And when browsing to an incorrect url, we have a blank page (or the error page of your browser).
To handle the error pages in your blazor app, you can add the line app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode/{0}"); at the end of your program.cs file, and then create a new razor page :
ErrorPage.razor
@page "/StatusCode/{status}"

<PageTitle>@Status</PageTitle>

<h1>@Status</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

You will have the status code in the parameter, and do what you want according to it (404, 500,...)
